# Can I use my laptop as a screen for Zotac ZBox Mini PC? (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, monitor, remote

Hi I have Xubuntu installed on a Zotac Zbox that I'm setting up as a server in a remote location (there's power), I was wondering if I could use my laptop as a monitor for this device instead of bringing my actual monitor out there?

Comment: What's the point of that? Do you want to manage that PC remotely? if so you're looking for remote desktop sharing. Or just access its contents?

Comment: @MichaelBay I need to do a "detect devices on network" to set up the software (ubiquiti aircontrol) from then on I'd just need to  ssh in to it I think

Comment: If you just need to install one software I don't understand the need for such an elaborate setup. Install it locally and it's do. You can't access remotely a machine that wasn't configured for that. Once configured then you can access it remotely.